# Can i add functions addtocart(), removefromcart(), createorder(), executeorder() to the user class?

Tags: oop, ooad

i'm trying to build an eshop application and this is my class diagram [image: class diagram uploaded to https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGhLz.png]

i have given responsibilities and functionality to my classes but it is not obvious for me how class user is going to interact with order and cart class. is it ok for example to add functions addtocart(), removefromcart(),  createorder(), executeorder() etc. , to the user class??? The problem for me is that these functions are irrelevant with the responsibilities of the user class, but on the other hand there is a composition relationship between them and at some how user class should use cart and order class.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would add these functions to the Cart-Class and not to the User-Class.

Comment: You say you don't understand how the user is going to interact with the cart and order.  I don't see it either.  For a User to place an order, there is no need for the cart/cart items.  You may need to rethink this one; just a little ;)

Comment: Why do you think that the user class needs to use the cart and order classes? Wouldn't a controller class use those classes, for example create an order from a cart?

Comment: md2perpe: because there is a 'has a' relationship between the user and the cart and also the user and the order. So the user asks from the order class to place an order. this is how o think of it.  but i think you have a point on this

Answer (score 0):

You need to break this design into subsystems: customer management, billing, catalogue, order, payment, and shopping.

You will also need subsystems to manage the user-interface and to manage data storage, but you usually have libraries and frameworks to simplify their implementations (e.g. MVC and persistence frameworks).

You might end up with classes that are similar in different subsystems (e.g. "customer" in customer management and in order), but you also need to consider that the classes play different roles in these different contexts.

I am not a big fan of DDD, but it is an easy introduction to application partitioning.